# I can not use grunt -cli and grunt serve in my web hosting

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-cli

I have developed a website on Node.js that runs perfectly on my local machine. I run my server with the command:

```
$ grunt serve
```

The problem is when i run my web application on my server online ( gandi server ). I can't use the command

```
$ grunt serve
```

Because i should install the package '' grunt-cli ''wich :

```
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
```

On server Gandi.net, i can't install global package, then i don't use the command

```
$ grunt
```

I try a program like

```
var grunt = require('grunt');

grunt.task.run("serve");
```

Program don't run.

I need help for run my grunt task '' serve '' without grunt -cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 0

`grunt` is a build tool and is generally not used to run servers other than local test servers. So the best solution is probably to get your server up and running using [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [`forever`](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) or something else instead of `grunt`.

As far as getting `grunt` running on the server, if you still need to do that, you have a few options.

Option 1 is the least disruptive to the system but may require the most understanding on your part to pull off successfully. Specifically, I'm not sure how much grief you will get from `grunt` if it finds itself in a non-global path.

Note that Option 1 doesn't require superuser privileges.

#### Option 1

From a shell in your home directory, you can install `grunt-cli` in without the `-g`. Then use a shell alias or your `PATH` environment variable so that you run grunt from `~/node_modules/.bin/grunt`.

#### Option 2

If you have superuser privileges, change the permissions on the global `node_modules` directory so that you have write access to it.

Some people recommend this over the next option for security reasons, but I think most people probably just go right to...

#### Option 3

If you have permission to do so on your server, you can use `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`.

Option 3 is the easiest but also requires the most trust in the packages that you are installing. Because [a package can do anything](https://github.com/joaojeronimo/rimrafall) once you start installing it with `sudo`, only use this option on packages you inspect and/or trust.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Just node_modules/.bin/grunt run it

Comment: Glad you found a solution. (Sounds like you ran `npm install grunt-cli` from your project root rather than your home directory. That will work too but yeah, then the `~/` part of the command has to go.)